# How can I go back to my original list after filtering ListView in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-listview

I am filtering houses according to their City address. I am using dropdown filter at first all houses are displayed, when I choose specific city ,e.g London, it will filter houses that locate in london from the "HouseList" but again if I choose Paris, it will try to filter the houses that locate in Paris from the Houses that locate in London. So how can I go back to original HouseList after each filter.
I'm using this line

***houselist =   newhouselist.where((u) => (u.address.contains(city))).toList();***

Answer (score 0):

You should keep a copy of your list, and add something like this to get a filtred copy of your list:

```
void main() {
  final a = A();
  print(a.l);
  print(a.list);
}

class A {
  List<int> list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12];

  List<int> get l => [...list.where((i) => i > 5)];
}
```

Comment: that will solve, but it if I'm using 10 different cities, I have to make 10 different copies?